# Stuck trying to open write stream on socket in OS X

Tags: c++, macos, sockets, network-programming, asyncsocket

After reading many examples online, I tried to write a short simple program to test a socket connection between two computers.  I have these two computers

- client, 192.168.0.116, running the program below
- server, 192.168.0.118, running http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/ in server listen mode on port 6237

I started out with an even simpler synchronous design, but moved to a runloop/async when that didn't work.

Symptom:  CFWriteStreamOpen returns true (success), but the stream stays in the kCFStreamStatusOpening state indefinitely.  The callback is never called to confirm open is complete (in fact it is never called for any event).

I suspected that somehow I may have a network problem (firewall, etc.) that might prevent this connection.  To disprove this theory, I ran http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/ on the client as well and the client and server connected fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CoreFoundation/CFStream.h>
using namespace std;

CFStreamClientContext myContext = {0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};

#define SA_HOST "192.168.0.118"
//#define SA_HOST "127.0.0.1"
#define SA_PORT 6237
UInt8 buf[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
UInt8 *wp = buf;
UInt16 bytesQueued = 5;
UInt16 bytesSent = 0;

static const CFOptionFlags kWriteStreamEvents =
kCFStreamEventEndEncountered |
kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred |
kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes |
kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted |
kCFStreamEventNone;

void WriteStreamCB(CFWriteStreamRef writeStream, CFStreamEventType event, void *clientCallBackInfo)
{
    switch (event)
    {
        case kCFStreamEventEndEncountered:
        {
            cout << "in CallBack: kCFStreamEventEndEncounteredd" << endl;
            CFWriteStreamClose(writeStream);
            break;
        }
        case kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred:
        {
            cout << "in CallBack: kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred" << endl;
            CFStreamError err = CFWriteStreamGetError(writeStream);
            cout << "in Callback: stream error, domain: " << err.domain << ", value: " << err.error << endl;
            break;
        }
        case kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes:
        {
            cout << "in CallBack: kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes" << endl;

            bytesSent = CFWriteStreamWrite(writeStream, buf, 5);
            if (bytesSent > 0)
            {
                bytesQueued -= bytesSent;
                wp += bytesSent;
                cout << "CFWriteStreamWrite wrote " << bytesSent << " bytes, " << bytesQueued << " left" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "CFWriteStreamWrite returned " << bytesSent << endl;
            }
            break;
        }
        case kCFStreamEventNone:
        {
            cout << "in CallBack: kCFStreamEventNone" << endl;
            break;
        }
        case kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        {
            cout << "in CallBack: kCFStreamEventNone" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    CFWriteStreamRef   writeStream;
    CFStringRef host = CFSTR(SA_HOST);
    UInt32 port = SA_PORT;

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host, port, NULL, &writeStream);
    CFWriteStreamSetClient(writeStream, kWriteStreamEvents, WriteStreamCB, &myContext);
    CFWriteStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(writeStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    if (!CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    while (true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe try creating a host using the same technique as this poster:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829228/cfwritestreamwrite-stopped-before-finishing

Specifically:
CFHostRef hostRef = CFHostCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault,(CFStringRef)iHostname);

Comment: Maybe `while (true);` is a too tight loop. Can you you replace that by `while (1) sleep(10);`? If that doesn't help, I'd use `strace` or `ltrace` to look closer at it.

Comment: You are not allowing the runloop to *run*. See if you can get the code to work with [RunLoopController](https://github.com/trojanfoe/RunLoopController), which I wrote to make it easier to integrate APIs that use the runloop with console programs.

Comment: CFHost doesn't seem to be available in the CoreFoundation.framework that I'm using.  Also, CFWriteStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost doesn't take a CFHostRef but rather a "CFStringRef host" in the CoreFoundation.framework that I'm using.  I do despise Objective-C code and I'm really hoping that what I'm trying is possible with C++.  I did see the CPU pegged in debug, so the tight while loop was an issue in starving the runloop...but when I added sleep(10), it did not change the symptom above.  Is there something that RunLoopController provides that I need in this case?

Comment: It has something to do with the RunLoop.  I went back to synchronous and it started working.  Probably I can't just expect the default RunLoop to take my code so easily...will look into creating my own.

Comment: ~3 days after I hit this problem and finally found that CFRunLoopRun() must be called AFTER CFWriteStreamOpen.  Not documented anywhere.  Cheers to those that search and find this later.

Answer (score 0):

> You are not allowing the runloop to run.

.

> ~3 days after I hit this problem and finally found that CFRunLoopRun() must be called AFTER CFWriteStreamOpen. Not documented anywhere. Cheers to those that search and find this later

Quoting comments for visibility. Point is, if your CF socket code is hung, you may need to run your run loop.

Additionally, if you're not doing the run loop & callback based API usage pattern, i.e. if you are doing blocking IO with `CFWriteStreamWrite` and not setting the "stream client", you may also be hung due to an error like a timeout.